# After table field altered insert api not working in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I modified my table structure and removed old fields with new fields and executed php artisan migrate:refresh from that moment my insert api not working giving

> "SQLSTATE exception: 1054 Unknown column 'oldfieldname' in 'field
> list'"

don't know but the query is working on old columns, I updated my model as per new field.

Comment: 1. Did you change the column name in your controller file?

Comment: Share your controller method that is handling the insert operation.